# React Apex Charts Won't Resize

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble changing the sizes of two Reach Apex charts. Just as a placeholder for now, I copied the starter code from the Apex Charts website and pasted it into my react app. I am trying to give the page a dashboard-type feel with few charts that are equally sized. But, I can't increase the size of one chart to match the other (I need to make the left one bigger).

Any idea how I can fix this? I tried altering the "height" of the chart, and they are both in divs that have the same formatting (aside from color of the div). Below is the code I took from Apex Charts and slightly altered. There is also an image that shows the difference in chart size.[image]

I am new to React and CSS, so I appreciate any advice (and patience) here.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          /*Overall win % chart*/
          series: [67],
          options: {
            chart1: {
              height: 190,
              type: 'radialBar',
              offsetY: -10
            },
            plotOptions: {
              radialBar: {
                startAngle: -135,
                endAngle: 135,
                dataLabels: {
                  name: {
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    color: undefined,
                    offsetY: 120
                  },
                  value: {
                    offsetY: 76,
                    fontSize: '22px',
                    color: undefined,
                    formatter: function (val) {
                      return val + "%";
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            fill: {
              type: 'gradient',
              gradient: {
                  shade: 'dark',
                  shadeIntensity: 0.15,
                  inverseColors: false,
                  opacityFrom: 1,
                  opacityTo: 1,
                  stops: [0, 50, 65, 91]
              },
            },
            stroke: {
              dashArray: 4
            },
            labels: [''],
          },
          /*iwatch chart*/
          series_iwatch: [76, 67, 61],
            options_iwatch: {
              chart: {
                height: 390,
                type: 'radialBar',
              },
              plotOptions: {
                radialBar: {
                  offsetY: 0,
                  startAngle: 0,
                  endAngle: 270,
                  hollow: {
                    margin: 5,
                    size: '30%',
                    background: 'transparent',
                    image: undefined,
                  },
                  dataLabels: {
                    name: {
                      show: false,
                    },
                    value: {
                      show: false,
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              colors: ['#1ab7ea', '#0084ff', '#39539E'],
              labels: ['Winner', 'Spread', 'Over/Under'],
              legend: {
                show: true,
                floating: true,
                fontSize: '16px',
                position: 'center',
                offsetX: 160,
                offsetY: 15,
                labels: {
                  useSeriesColors: true,
                },
                markers: {
                  size: 0
                },
                formatter: function(seriesName, opts) {
                  return seriesName + ":  " + opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex]
                },
                itemMargin: {
                  vertical: 3
                }
              },
              responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 480,
                options: {
                  legend: {
                      show: false
                  }
                }
              }]
            }
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. For experienced react users, the solution will be obvious, but for me it was not. Chart heigh and width formatting needs to go in the  tag itself, not the formatting options for the chart:

```
    <div id="chart2">
              <ReactApexChart options={this.state.options_iwatch} 
               series={this.state.series_iwatch} type="radialBar" height={390} />
    </div>
```